# What is in *.Configuration.Design assemblies in Enterprise Library

Tags: enterprise-library

I generally understand Enterprise Library, but one thing puzzles me: What is the prupose of  `*.Configuration.Design` assemblies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that they have metadata that helps the designer display controls, etc.  But I don't have those assemblies handy to inspect.

Have you looked at them in ndisasm, or reflector?

Comment: These libraries help present enterprise library configuration to user and shouldn't be referenced in project